# When is sequence limit equivalent function limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function on $X$ into $Y$ where $X, Y$ are topological spaces, define the function limit of $f$ at $x_0 \in X$ as follows

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = y_0$$

where $y_0 \in Y$ if for each open set $U_Y \subseteq Y$ containing $y_0$, there exists an open set $U_X$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(U_X) \subseteq U_y$ ($\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ recovers the usual definition of continuous function)

Let $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence, define the sequential limit of $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ as follows

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = x_0$$

where $x_0 \in X$ if for each open set $U_X \subseteq X$ containing $x_0$, there exists a $K_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k \in U_X$ for all $k \geq K_1$

Define the next limit

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k) = y_0$$

where $y_0 \in Y$ if for each open set $U_Y \subseteq Y$ containing $y_0$, there exists a $K_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_k) \in U_Y$ for all $k \geq K_2$

I am wondering when is $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k) = y_0$ for all possible sequences $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ enough to conclude that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = y_0$

Comment: When $X$ is first countable.

Comment: @Ningxin please help me understand. You answered the question. Why did you leave the answer as a comment? This seems to be an epidemic on SE right now.

Comment: @IAAW I didn't answer the question. I didn't explain what "first countable" means, nor why it works. I gave a hint, a term that OP can search and find the actual answer himself.

Another reason is that it is not encouraged here to answer a question that has already been asked and answered many times.

Comment: You can have a look at the Wikipedia article on [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).
There are also various posts on this site related to the topic, such as: [Continuity and image of convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53236)
Some post with a proof about first-countable spaces: [Proofs about continuity and convergence in topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777865), 
[Proof for sequentially continuous function with a first countable domain is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3385527) and ...

Comment: ... [Theorem 30.1 (b) in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The sequential criterion for continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3233324).
Some posts with countexamples:
[Give an example of a function $f :X \to Y$ which is sequential continuous but not continuous where $X$ and $Y$ are some topological spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1412415),
[Example of topological spaces where sequential continuity does not imply continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1419938) and 
[Example where $f$ is discontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/745036).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ has a **countable local basis** $\mathcal{B}$ at $x_0$, i.e. there is a countable collection of open neighbourhood $\mathcal{B} = \{ B_k: k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ of $x_0$ such that for each open neighbourhood $U_X \subseteq X$ of $x_0$, there exists a $B_k \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B_k \subseteq U$.
We construct an open neighbourhood $A_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^n B_k$ of $x_0$  for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq ...$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{A_k: k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is also a **countable local basis** at $x_0$ as $A_k \subseteq B_k$.

Suppose the opposite, there exists an open neighbourhood $U_Y$ of $y_0$ such that for all open set $U_X$ containing $x_0$ then $f(U_X) \setminus U_Y \neq \emptyset$.

For each $A_k, k \in \mathbb{N}$, choose $\bar{x}_k \in A_k$ such that $f(\bar{x}_k) \notin U_Y$. The sequence $(\bar{x}_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x_0$ as each open neighbourhood $U_X \subseteq X$ of $x_0$ contains an $A_k$ and that $A_k$ contains all $A_{k+1}, A_{k+2}, ...$.

However, $(f(\bar{x}_k))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converges to $y_0$ since there exists an open neighbourhood $U_Y$ of $y_0$ such that $f(\bar{x}_k) \notin U_Y$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Contradiction.

Thanks to Ningxin for their hint.